# Solving system of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Any ideas how to solve this system:

$$ \array{\dot x(t) = \dfrac{t-x(t)}{\sqrt{(t-x(t))^2+y(t)^2}}, \\
          \dot y(t) = \dfrac{y(t)}{\sqrt{(t-x(t))^2+y(t)^2}},   \\
          x(0) = 0, \quad y(0) = L. } $$

Comment: I don't know if I can solve this, but here is my attempted start. Notice how $t-x(t)$ is a pattern that always appears. Try a substitution:$u(t)=t-x(t) \rightarrow \dot u=1-\dot x$. Thus, you have the following.
$$1-\dot u = \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+y^2}}$$
$$\dot y = \frac{y}{\sqrt{u^2+y^2}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, expressed on parametric form is given in attachment (Sorry, today I have not enough time to rewrite it in latex).

[image]